# Input of words converted to numbers in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program to launch in Windows console that will ask "What is the color of the first band" in a resistor, so when you type something such as "red" it will input a 2 into the float. The problem I'm having is that not only can I not figure out how to make "red" into "2" but whenever I try to input text on the console it will display the rest of the printf's and skip to the end.

This is what I have thus far, I commented out the third and fourth input just so I could troubleshoot easier.

```
//Color bands

#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    double first;
    double second;
    //double third;
    //double fourth;
    double total_resist;
    double black, brown, red = 2, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet, gray, white;

    black = 0;
    brown = 1;
    red = 2;
    orange = 3;
    yellow = 4;
    green = 5;
    blue = 6;
    violet = 7;
    gray = 8;
    white = 9;

    printf("Input first color band> ");
    scanf("%lf", &first);

    printf("Input second color band> ");
    scanf("%lf", &second);

    total_resist = first + second;// + second + third + fourth;

    printf("\nTotal resistance is %.lf\n", total_resist);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `scanf` will never convert the string `red` to the float `2`. You need to do it by yourself.

Comment: you need to make a lookup table. color codes are anyways fixed. are you not taking the precision into account?. maybe you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
char color[20];

printf("Input first color band> ");
scanf("%19s", color);

if (!strcmp(color, "red"))
    first = 2.0;
else if (...)
```

Obviously the next step is to make a function:

```
double color2number(const char *name)
```

Comment: And the step after creating a function is to use an array for the names and hence the numbers, so you iterate instead of a list of 10 valid alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int colour_value(char const *colour)
{
    const char *band[] =
    {
        "black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow",
        "green", "blue", "violet", "grey", "white"
    };
    enum { NUM_BANDS = sizeof(band) / sizeof(band[0]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BANDS; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(colour, band[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    double total_resistance = 0.0;
    const char *ordinals[] = { "zeroth", "first", "second", "third", "fourth" };
    char colour[32];
    char band[4][8];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int value;
        printf("Input %-6s color band> ", ordinals[i + 1]);
        if (scanf("%s", colour) != 1)
            break;
        if ((value = colour_value(colour)) == -1)
            break;
        total_resistance = total_resistance * 10.0 + value;
        strcpy(band[i], colour);
    }

    if (i == 4)
    {
        printf("%s", "Bands: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            printf(" %s", band[i]);
        printf("\nTotal resistance is %.lf\n", total_resistance);
    }
    else
        puts("Oops!");

    return(0);
}
```

Example runs:

```
Input first  color band> orange
Input second color band> green
Input third  color band> violet 
Input fourth color band> brown
Bands:  orange green violet brown
Total resistance is 3571


Input first  color band> red
Input second color band> yellow
Input third  color band> black
Input fourth color band> blue
Bands:  red yellow black blue
Total resistance is 2406
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>



int color2nr(char* color){
if(color=="red")
   return red;
else if(color=="orange")
   return orange;
...  
}
```

Do the same thing all the other colors...

```
main(void)
{
double first;
double second;
double third;
double fourth;
double total_resist;
double black, brown, red = 2, orange, yellow, green, blue, violet, gray, white;

black=0;
brown=1;
red = 2;
orange = 3;
yellow = 4;
green = 5;
blue = 6;
violet = 7;
gray = 8;
white = 9;

char[10] buf;
printf("Input first color band> ");
scanf("%s", buf);
double first=color2nr(buf);

printf("Input second color band> ");
scanf("%s", buf);
double second=color2nr(buf);


total_resist = first + second;// + second + third + fourth;


printf("\nTotal resist is %.lf\n", total_resist);



return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) try using **enum**
```

eg :
    `typedef enum {black,brown,red...}colorcodes;`

declare variables as so..

```
colorcodes FstColor, SndColor;

2) `scanf("%s\n",FstColorStr)` and not `scanf("%lf",bSndColorStr);`

3)  if(strcmp(FstColorStr,"red")) FstColor = red and so on for all other colors.

4) tot_resist = FstColor * pow(10,SndColor); //include math.h
```